# Как уменьшить/увеличить размер массива

Tags: java, массивы

Мне в классе нужно создать массив (именно массив, не список) из X элементов, как затем размер этого массива увеличить и уменьшить на 1 элемент (но чтобы не было пустых ячеек памяти), мне нужно пользоваться начальным массивом, так как именно его я передаю во все методы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//создаем массив на 10 элементов
int[] array = new int[10];

//уменьшаем массив на 1 и копируем туда из исходного массива
int[] newArray = new int[9]
System.arrayCopy(array, 0, dest, 0, newArray.length);

//увеличиваем массив на 1 и копируем туда из исходного массива
//Стоит заметить, что в конце у нового массива будет стоять значение по умолчанию (для int это 0)
int[] newArray = new int[11]
System.arrayCopy(array, 0, dest, 0, newArray.length);
```

Comment: а как мне быть если методы в классе используют начальный массив (array), мне нужно ведь будет продолжить пользоваться этим массивом, но уже с обновленными значениями

Comment: Присвоить переменной array ссылку newArray